# How do I set a 4d array with a 2d array of indexes using Numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, opencv, multidimensional-array

I just started learning numpy and Python a few days ago, so I apologize if I've made any obvious errors.

Basically I want to convert the following for loop into a faster solution. I know this can be done with numpy, I'm just not sure how.

```
img = np.zeros((height,width,3), np.uint8) #image matrix
indexes = np.zeros((height,width), np.uint8)

for y in range(height):
    for x in range(width):
        img[y][x] = vid[indexes[y][x]][y][x] #for 1 pixel

#"vid" is a 4d array with vid[frameNumber] being one image.
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an index array via [`np.ogrid`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ogrid.html):

```
y, x = np.ogrid[:height, :width]
img = vid[indexes[y, x], y, x]
```

Comment: This seems like a great solution except I'm getting this error: TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index.

Comment: @Titan Could you update your question with that example?

Comment: Using some dummy data, it looks like you actually need to use `vid[indexes[y, x], y, x]` (and not reshape) to get the right results.

Comment: @jirassimok I attempted your solution and got this error: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple

Comment: @Titan Can you also provide sample data for `vid`. If `vid` is 4d, then `vid[indexes[y][x]][y][x]` is a 1d sub-array and not an element. Is that correct?

Comment: @Titan Ah, it sounds like the problem is that `vid` is a list, not a NumPy array. Try converting it to NumPy (e.g. with `np.asarray`).

Comment: @jirassimok is right, I has vid as a list. His solution also worked with no errors! Thank you both.

Answer (score 1):

I would do:

```
y,x = np.meshgrid(np.arange(height),np.arange(width))
img = vid[indexes, y, x]

print(img.shape)
# output (height, width, 3)
```